# Getting asset file doesn't have targetframework exception while publishing in .net core project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-3.1

I don't understand how csproj and references play together. And I created a basic .Net Core app and it's building fine locally. But when I am trying to publish it I am getting exception as below.

> error NETSDK1047: Assets file
> 'C:\Users\source\repos\AWSLambda7\AWSLambda7\obj\project.assets.json'
> doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1/linux-x64'. Ensure
> that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.1' in the
> TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include
> 'linux-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.
> [C:\Users\source\repos\AWSLambda7\AWSLambda7\AWSLambda7.csproj]

Below is the code snippet

```
public class Function
{
    public async Task FunctionHandler(SQSEvent evnt, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        foreach (var message in evnt.Records)
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

The csproj file looks like below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The obj\project.assets.json file looks like below

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1": {
      "Amazon.Lambda.Core/1.1.0": {
        "type": "package",
        "compile": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Amazon.Lambda.Core.dll": {}
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Amazon.Lambda.Core.dll": {}
        }
      },
      "Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson/2.0.0": {
        "type": "package",
        "dependencies": {
          "Amazon.Lambda.Core": "1.1.0"
        },
        "compile": {
          "lib/netcoreapp3.1/Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.dll": {}
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netcoreapp3.1/Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.dll": {}
        }
      },
      "Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents/1.1.0": {
        "type": "package",
        "compile": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents.dll": {}
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents.dll": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "libraries": {
    "Amazon.Lambda.Core/1.1.0": {
      "sha512": "ueGId8b4DEHoVWkHDs3iAJH8IUSAUGu5AqkoI/Syl4RuByzik7lz9IjoImQ==",
      "type": "package",
      "path": "amazon.lambda.core/1.1.0",
      "files": [
        ".nupkg.metadata",
        ".signature.p7s",
        "amazon.lambda.core.1.1.0.nupkg.sha512",
        "amazon.lambda.core.nuspec",
        "lib/netstandard1.3/Amazon.Lambda.Core.dll",
        "lib/netstandard1.3/Amazon.Lambda.Core.xml",
        "lib/netstandard2.0/Amazon.Lambda.Core.dll",
        "lib/netstandard2.0/Amazon.Lambda.Core.xml"
      ]
    },
    "Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson/2.0.0": {
      "sha512": "En67XZpjBILNrLdb/7HqGtqkPjoRYDjViY4+PEn1CAe53FNStU/vbcVtDvDyvQeUnFgMui3zvMdlsjJIzBPHdQ==",
      "type": "package",
      "path": "amazon.lambda.serialization.systemtextjson/2.0.0",
      "files": [
        ".nupkg.metadata",
        ".signature.p7s",
        "amazon.lambda.serialization.systemtextjson.2.0.0.nupkg.sha512",
        "amazon.lambda.serialization.systemtextjson.nuspec",
        "lib/netcoreapp3.1/Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.dll",
        "lib/netcoreapp3.1/Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.xml"
      ]
    },
    "Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents/1.1.0": {
      "sha512": "AD6rELASxItdSSR1Vj7X7pEE8OeGIADJkYer9dvHtXP+2Nhp==",
      "type": "package",
      "path": "amazon.lambda.sqsevents/1.1.0",
      "files": [
        ".nupkg.metadata",
        ".signature.p7s",
        "amazon.lambda.sqsevents.1.1.0.nupkg.sha512",
        "amazon.lambda.sqsevents.nuspec",
        "lib/netstandard1.3/Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents.dll",
        "lib/netstandard1.3/Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents.xml",
        "lib/netstandard2.0/Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents.dll",
        "lib/netstandard2.0/Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents.xml"
      ]
    }
  },
  "projectFileDependencyGroups": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1": [
      "Amazon.Lambda.Core >= 1.1.0",
      "Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents >= 1.1.0",
      "Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson >= 2.0.0"
    ]
  },
  "packageFolders": {
    "C:\\Users\\.nuget\\packages\\": {},
    "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder": {}
  },
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "restore": {
      "projectUniqueName": "C:\\Users\\source\\repos\\AWSLambda7\\AWSLambda7\\AWSLambda7.csproj",
      "projectName": "AWSLambda7",
      "projectPath": "C:\\Users\\source\\repos\\AWSLambda7\\AWSLambda7\\AWSLambda7.csproj",
      "packagesPath": "C:\\Users\\.nuget\\packages\\",
      "outputPath": "C:\\Users\\source\\repos\\AWSLambda7\\AWSLambda7\\obj\\",
      "projectStyle": "PackageReference",
      "fallbackFolders": [
        "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder"
      ],
      "configFilePaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\AppData\\Roaming\\NuGet\\NuGet.Config",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NuGet\\Config\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config"
      ],
      "originalTargetFrameworks": [
        "netcoreapp3.1"
      ],
      "sources": {
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\NuGetPackages\\": {},
        "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json": {}
      },
      "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp3.1": {
          "projectReferences": {}
        }
      },
      "warningProperties": {
        "warnAsError": [
          "NU1605"
        ]
      }
    },
    "frameworks": {
      "netcoreapp3.1": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Amazon.Lambda.Core": {
            "target": "Package",
            "version": "[1.1.0, )"
          },
          "Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents": {
            "target": "Package",
            "version": "[1.1.0, )"
          },
          "Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson": {
            "target": "Package",
            "version": "[2.0.0, )"
          }
        },
        "imports": [
          "net461",
          "net462",
          "net47",
          "net471",
          "net472",
          "net48"
        ],
        "assetTargetFallback": true,
        "warn": true,
        "frameworkReferences": {
          "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "privateAssets": "all"
          }
        },
        "runtimeIdentifierGraphPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\3.1.301\\RuntimeIdentifierGraph.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note that project builds fine in VS-2019 in Windows 10 machine.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are building a project directly. which will by default will support windows server, AWS lambda internally will use Linux OS. We need to Build & Package target OS as Linux
Below are some of the steps you need to follow

1. Make sure you are added a Lambda serializer Below is code for the same
   [assembly:LambdaSerializer(typeof(DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]
2. Open a Command prompt and execute this below command it will build and will package with the support of Aws lambda ready package (you must install AWS cli tools)

   > dotnet lambda package

If you don't have a AWS CLI tool use this below command

dotnet publish --output "[output folderpath]" --configuration "Release" --framework "netcoreapp3.1" /p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=true **--runtime linux-x64** --self-contained false